# Xamarin: Android packages compatibility problem

Tags: android, xamarin, plugins, package

I'm try to using this nuget package:

https://github.com/vikram-ma/PushNotificationPlugin

This package has Dependencies like:

- MonoAndroid, Version=v8.0

  - Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>=26.0.2)
  - Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (= 60.1142.0)
- .NETStandard, Version=v1.0

  - NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)

When I want to install it I got the error message:

> Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.1 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 28.0.0.1)'

**My related packages:**

> package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="26.1.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid80"

I can't installing this package. I really need it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you want to implement push notification in Android .You can use the package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AppCenter.Push/2.1.1 .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT
Thanks for the answer. 
I realised I had other dependencies depend on each others and that was the problem.